# Can I use "addEventListener" on a querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an `variableName.addEventListener("transitionend", function ()` to all of my classes named `.aboutCollapsible`. The code provided below only works on the first element due to it being `querySelector` and not `querySelectorAll`.

**JavaScript Code:** *Reasoning for writing all of the code is for context, in case that is required to understand the question.*

```js
//var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
const el = document.querySelector(".aboutCollapsible");
//var i;
//
//for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
//    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
//        this.classList.toggle("active");
//        var content = this.nextElementSibling
//        if (content.style.maxHeight < "100%") {
//            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            el.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
                content.style.maxHeight = "100%"
            });
//        } else {
//            content.style.transitionDuration = "0s"
//            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
//            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
//            content.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"
//            content.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            el.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
                content.style.maxHeight = null
                content.style.transitionDuration = null
            });
//        }
//    });
//}
```

**I get the following error when changing `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll`:**

> TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function

How would I go about solving the issue of adding `addEventListener("transitionend", function () {` to all of my classes named `.aboutCollapsible`?

**UPDATE:** This seems to work, however, isn't there a better way. Do I really have to run a forEach loop every time it the click is triggered? Can I just not call the transitionend function instead?

```js
// Button Collapsible
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling
        if (content.style.maxHeight < "100%") {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
                content.style.maxHeight = "100%"
            }));
        } else {
            content.style.transitionDuration = "0s"
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            content.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"
            content.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
                content.style.maxHeight = null
                content.style.transitionDuration = null
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either iterate through it:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible")].forEach(e => e.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {...}));
// Or:
document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {...}));
```

Or use jQuery:

```
$(".aboutCollapsible").on("transitionend", function() {...});
```

Comment: spread operator isn't required?

Comment: I just prefer converting it to an array - I'll add the alternative too @shrys.

Comment: @JackBashford This really helped, however, can you check the updated code in the main post. I think I must have written it incorrectly?